# How to free memory from another file?

Tags: c, allocation

I am learning about dynamic memory allocation.

I wrote a few lines to understand how pointers, tables and memory allocation work. I have a `malloc` function but I don't know where to put the `free` function?

main.c :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #include "allocation.c"

    int main(void)
    {

        int count = 5;
        int initValue = 2;
        int increment = 3;

        int *result = arithmeticSequence(count, initValue, increment);
        printf("Adresse de mon pointeur : %p\n", result);

        for(int i=0 ; i < count ; i++)
        {
            printf("[%d]", *result);
            result++;
        }
        return 0;
     }
```

allocation.c :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "allocation.h"

int *arithmeticSequence(int count, int initValue, int increment)
{
    int *table = NULL;

    table = malloc(count * sizeof(int));

    if(table == NULL)
        exit(1);

    for(int i=0 ; i < count ; i++)
    {
        table[i] = initValue + i * increment;
    }

    printf("Adresse de l'element 0 de la table : %p\n", &table[0]);

    return &table[0];

}
```

Comment: Typically at a point when no longer needed. For your example, before the return in main would be a good place.

Comment: Just FYI, you can replace 'return &table[0]' with just 'return table'

Comment: Another script? Do you mean file? In any case, C is probably the farthest you can get from a scripting language.

Comment: Don't call C code a "script". This is compiled to machine code, it's no longer source, so the term "script" is very misleading and confusing.

Comment: ok thanks for all your answers. I changed "script" to "file" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the issue of *object ownership*.  Whatever function (or class, module, etc) *owns* the object (or pointer) is responsible for making sure that it is freed (or destroyed) under all possible conditions, as soon as possible after it is no longer needed.  It's also important to make sure that nothing else besides the owner frees it.

As a programmer, you need to decide what's the best "owner" of each pointer. In this program, the best choice is the `main` function.

Comment: Don't bother freeing memory just before falling off the end of main.

Comment: @Joshua, I disagree.  It's good form.  Also, if you fail to free it, you would trigger a report from any memory-leak detection tools.